# When to write an explicit return statement in Groovy?

Tags: coding-style, groovy

At the moment I am working on a Groovy/Grails project (which I'm quite new in) and I wonder whether it is good practice to omit the `return` keyword in Groovy methods. As far as I know you have to explicitly insert the keyword i.e. for guard clauses, so should one use it also everywhere else? In my opinion the additional `return` keyword increases readability. Or is it something you just have to get used to? What is your experience with that topic?

Some examples:

```
def foo(boolean bar) {
    // Not consistent
    if (bar) {
        return positiveBar()
    }
    negativeBar()
}

def foo2() {
    // Special Grails example
    def entitiy = new Entity(foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar')
    entity.save flush: true
    // Looks strange to me this way
    entity
}
```

Comment: There's a similar issue in Perl: a function returns the last evaluated expression in tbe absence of a `return` statement. Personally, I always use the explicit `return`, but I don't know Groovy.

Comment: Personally I'd use the implicit `return` *only* when it's perfectly clear. `toString` is a typical example: it's a one-liner and the value computed is obviously the return value. But then again, I haven't programmed enough Groovy to know if that fits into what the larger community thinks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I certain would add the return, as it makes the intention clearer to any person (including yourself) who may come and update/maintain the code later on.

Otherwise it might look like a typing error.

The other thing is to remember to declare functions/closures that are expected to return a void as 'void' - again to make it clearer to future maintainers what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 18):

#### Clarity is King.

Do what is most clear to the fellow programmer who has to read your code after you write it.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an argument for omitting the return statements ([Source](http://codetojoy.blogspot.com/2009/08/understated-feature-in-groovy.html)):

> **An Understated Feature in Groovy**
>
> **Background**
>
> I have worked with Groovy for awhile, but have been averse to one
>   feature: the implicit return of the last expression evaluated. For
>   example:

```
def getFoo() {
  def foo = null
  if (something) {
    foo = new Foo()
  }
  foo // no 'return' necessary
}
```

> In the above code, I would use return because it felt safer to me. I
>   tended to agree with Eric's post (with respect to explicit returns).
>
> **Revelation**
>
> I get it now, and it's all thanks to the enhanced collection methods
>   in Groovy.
>
> Consider the collect method. It transforms a list by applying a
>   function. In pseudocode:

```
[ a, b, c, d] => [ f(a), f(b), f(c), f(d) ]
```

> With that in mind, here's another example:

```
class Composer {
  def name
  // def era, etc
}

def list = [ 'Bach', 'Beethoven', 'Brahms' ]

// the closure returns the new Composer object, as it is the last
// expression evaluated.

def composers = list.collect { item -> new Composer(name : item) }

assert 'Bach' == composers[0].name
```

> The idea is simply to build a list of Composer objects from a list of
>   strings. As noted in the comment, the closure passed to collect uses
>   the implicit return to great effect. At one time, I would have taken
>   3-4 lines to express that idea.
>
> But now, this code is not merely concise: it is truly elegant. Very
>   reminiscent of other languages such as Python.
>
> **The Take-Home Message**
>
> There are many lists of excellent Groovy features. However we rarely
>   see 'implicit return' listed. I'm a fan: it greases the wheels for
>   other features.
>
> I realize it is available in many languages: I just haven't used it in
>   Groovy. I suspect in a few weeks I won't be able to live without it.